# Modify training function of 3 nets with shared classifier

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network, mnist, vgg-net

I have 3 VGG: VGGA, VGGB and VGG*, trained with the following training function:

```
def train(nets, loaders, optimizer, criterion, epochs=20, dev=None, save_param=False, model_name="valerio"):
    # try:
      nets = [n.to(dev) for n in nets]

      model_a = module_unwrap(nets[0], True)
      model_b = module_unwrap(nets[1], True)
      model_c = module_unwrap(nets[2], True)

      reg_loss = nn.MSELoss()

      criterion.to(dev)
      reg_loss.to(dev)

      # Initialize history
      history_loss = {"train": [], "val": [], "test": []}
      history_accuracy = {"train": [], "val": [], "test": []}
      # Store the best val accuracy
      best_val_accuracy = 0

      # Process each epoch
      for epoch in range(epochs):
        # Initialize epoch variables
        sum_loss = {"train": 0, "val": 0, "test": 0}
        sum_accuracy = {"train": [0,0,0], "val": [0,0,0], "test": [0,0,0]}

        progbar = None
        # Process each split
        for split in ["train", "val", "test"]:
          if split == "train":
            for n in nets:
              n.train()
            widgets = [
              ' [', pb.Timer(), '] ',
              pb.Bar(),
              ' [', pb.ETA(), '] ', pb.Variable('ta','[Train Acc: {formatted_value}]')
            ]

            progbar = pb.ProgressBar(max_value=len(loaders[split][0]),widgets=widgets,redirect_stdout=True)

          else:
            for n in nets:
              n.eval()
          # Process each batch
          for j,((input_a, labels_a),(input_b, labels_b)) in enumerate(zip(loaders[split][0],loaders[split][1])):

            input_a = input_a.to(dev)
            input_b = input_b.to(dev)

            labels_a = labels_a.long().to(dev)
            labels_b = labels_b.long().to(dev)
            #print(labels_a.shape)
            #labels_a = labels_a.squeeze()
            #labels_b = labels_b.squeeze()
            
            #labels_a = labels_a.unsqueeze(1)
            #labels_b = labels_b.unsqueeze(1)
            #print(labels_a.shape)
            #labels_a = labels_a.argmax(-1)
            #labels_b = labels_b.argmax(-1)

            inputs = torch.cat([input_a,input_b],axis=0)
            labels = torch.cat([labels_a, labels_b])

            #labels  = labels.squeeze()
            #print(labels.shape)
            #labels = labels.argmax(-1)

            # Reset gradients
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            # Compute output
            features_a = nets[0](input_a)
            features_b = nets[1](input_b)
            features_c = nets[2](inputs)

            pred_a = torch.squeeze(nets[3](features_a))
            pred_b = torch.squeeze(nets[3](features_b))
            pred_c = torch.squeeze(nets[3](features_c))

            loss = criterion(pred_a, labels_a) + criterion(pred_b, labels_b) + criterion(pred_c, labels)

            for n in model_a:
              layer_a = model_a[n]
              layer_b = model_b[n]
              layer_c = model_c[n]
              if (isinstance(layer_a,nn.Conv2d)):
                loss += lambda_reg * reg_loss(combo_fn(layer_a.weight,layer_b.weight),layer_c.weight)
                if (layer_a.bias is not None):
                  loss += lambda_reg * reg_loss(combo_fn(layer_a.bias, layer_b.bias), layer_c.bias)

            # Update loss
            sum_loss[split] += loss.item()
            # Check parameter update
            if split == "train":
              # Compute gradients
              loss.backward()
              # Optimize
              optimizer.step()

            # Compute accuracy

            #https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/bcewithlogitsloss-and-model-accuracy-calculation/59293/ 2
            #pred_labels_a = (pred_a >= 0.0).long()  # Binarize predictions to 0 and 1
            #pred_labels_b = (pred_b >= 0.0).long()  # Binarize predictions to 0 and 1
            #pred_labels_c = (pred_c >= 0.0).long()  # Binarize predictions to 0 and 1

            #print(pred_a.shape)

            _,pred_label_a = torch.max(pred_a, dim = 1)
            pred_labels_a = (pred_label_a == labels_a).float()

            _,pred_label_b = torch.max(pred_b, dim = 1)
            pred_labels_b = (pred_label_b == labels_b).float()

            _,pred_label_c = torch.max(pred_c, dim = 1)
            pred_labels_c = (pred_label_c == labels).float()

            batch_accuracy_a = pred_labels_a.sum().item() / len(labels_a)
            batch_accuracy_b = pred_labels_b.sum().item() / len(labels_b)
            batch_accuracy_c = pred_labels_c.sum().item() / len(labels)

            # Update accuracy
            sum_accuracy[split][0] += batch_accuracy_a
            sum_accuracy[split][1] += batch_accuracy_b
            sum_accuracy[split][2] += batch_accuracy_c


            if (split=='train'):
              progbar.update(j, ta=batch_accuracy_c)

        if (progbar is not None):
          progbar.finish()
        # Compute epoch loss/accuracy
        epoch_loss = {split: sum_loss[split] / len(loaders[split][0]) for split in ["train", "val", "test"]}
        epoch_accuracy = {split: [sum_accuracy[split][i] / len(loaders[split][0]) for i in range(len(sum_accuracy[split])) ] for split in ["train", "val", "test"]}

        # # Store params at the best validation accuracy
        # if save_param and epoch_accuracy["val"] > best_val_accuracy:
        #   # torch.save(net.state_dict(), f"{net.__class__.__name__}_best_val.pth")
        #   torch.save(net.state_dict(), f"{model_name}_best_val.pth")
        #   best_val_accuracy = epoch_accuracy["val"]

        print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}:")
        # Update history
        for split in ["train", "val", "test"]:
          history_loss[split].append(epoch_loss[split])
          history_accuracy[split].append(epoch_accuracy[split])
          # Print info
          print(f"\t{split}\tLoss: {epoch_loss[split]:0.5}\tVGG 1:{epoch_accuracy[split][0]:0.5}"
                f"\tVGG 2:{epoch_accuracy[split][1]:0.5}\tVGG *:{epoch_accuracy[split][2]:0.5}")

      if save_param:
        torch.save({'vgg_a':nets[0].state_dict(),'vgg_b':nets[1].state_dict(),'vgg_star':nets[2].state_dict(),'classifier':nets[3].state_dict()},f'{model_name}.pth')
```

For each epoch of training the result is this:
[image: Training]

Then, I have a combined model which sums the weights of VGGA and VGGB:

```
DO = 'TEST'
if (DO=='TRAIN'):
  train(nets, loaders, optimizer, criterion, epochs=50, dev=dev,save_param=True)
else:          
  state_dicts = torch.load('valerio.pth')
  model1.load_state_dict(state_dicts['vgg_a']) #questi state_dict vengono dalla funzione di training
  model2.load_state_dict(state_dicts['vgg_b'])
  model3.load_state_dict(state_dicts['vgg_star'])
  classifier.load_state_dict(state_dicts['classifier'])

  test(model1,classifier,test_loader_all)
  test(model2, classifier, test_loader_all)
  test(model3, classifier, test_loader_all)

  summed_state_dict = OrderedDict()

  for key in state_dicts['vgg_star']:
    if key.find('conv') >=0:
      print(key)
      summed_state_dict[key] = combo_fn(state_dicts['vgg_a'][key],state_dicts['vgg_b'][key])
    else:
      summed_state_dict[key] = state_dicts['vgg_star'][key]

  model3.load_state_dict(summed_state_dict)
  test(model3, classifier, test_loader_all)
```

where the test function is this:

```
def test(net,classifier, loader):

      net.to(dev)
      classifier.to(dev)

      net.eval()

      sum_accuracy = 0

      # Process each batch
      for j, (input, labels) in enumerate(loader):

        input = input.to(dev)
        labels = labels.float().to(dev)

        features = net(input)

        pred = torch.squeeze(classifier(features))

        # https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/bcewithlogitsloss-and-model-accuracy-calculation/59293/ 2
        #pred_labels = (pred >= 0.0).long()  # Binarize predictions to 0 and 1
        _,pred_label = torch.max(pred, dim = 1)
        pred_labels = (pred_label == labels).float()

        batch_accuracy = pred_labels.sum().item() / len(labels)

        # Update accuracy
        sum_accuracy += batch_accuracy

      epoch_accuracy = sum_accuracy / len(loader)

      print(f"Accuracy after sum: {epoch_accuracy:0.5}")
```

And the result of this aggregation is the following:
[image: Test]

I want to modify my training function in order to print the same things of the first image, plus the accuracy of the aggregated model (the highlighted part in red of the second picture). So basically, for each epoch, accuracies of VGGA, VGGB, VGG* and combined VGG, print these accuracies and continue with the training. I tried to add this model combo but I failed, because I did not able to insert into each epoch, but only at the end of the training. I was trying to add in the training function, between `print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}:")`and

```
# Update history
for split in ["train", "val", "test"]:
```

the code with the part of state_dict, but i am doing something wrong, i do not know what.
Can I reuse the code of the test, or I have to write new code?
Do you think i have to save the state_dict for each epoch, or i can do something else? Like `model_c.parameters()=model_a.parameters()+model_b.parameters()` (which does not work, already tried)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved, here is the solution of how I modified my training function:

```py
def train(nets, loaders, optimizer, criterion, epochs=20, dev=None, save_param=False, model_name="valerio"):
  # try:
  nets = [n.to(dev) for n in nets]

  model_a = module_unwrap(nets[0], True)
  model_b = module_unwrap(nets[1], True)
  model_c = module_unwrap(nets[2], True)

  reg_loss = nn.MSELoss()

  criterion.to(dev)
  reg_loss.to(dev)

  # Initialize history
  history_loss = {"train": [], "val": [], "test": []}
  history_accuracy = {"train": [], "val": [], "test": []}
  history_test = 0
  # Store the best val accuracy
  best_val_accuracy = 0

  # Process each epoch
  for epoch in range(epochs):
    # Initialize epoch variables
    sum_loss = {"train": 0, "val": 0, "test": 0}
    sum_accuracy = {"train": [0,0,0], "val": [0,0,0], "test": [0,0,0]}

    progbar = None
    # Process each split
    for split in ["train", "val", "test"]:
      if split == "train":
        for n in nets:
          n.train()
        widgets = [
          ' [', pb.Timer(), '] ',
          pb.Bar(),
          ' [', pb.ETA(), '] ', pb.Variable('ta','[Train Acc: {formatted_value}]')
        ]

        progbar = pb.ProgressBar(max_value=len(loaders[split][0]),widgets=widgets,redirect_stdout=True)

      else:
        for n in nets:
          n.eval()
      # Process each batch
      for j,((input_a, labels_a),(input_b, labels_b)) in enumerate(zip(loaders[split][0],loaders[split][1])):

        input_a = input_a.to(dev)
        input_b = input_b.to(dev)

        labels_a = labels_a.long().to(dev)
        labels_b = labels_b.long().to(dev)
        #print(labels_a.shape)
        #labels_a = labels_a.squeeze()
        #labels_b = labels_b.squeeze()

        #labels_a = labels_a.unsqueeze(1)
        #labels_b = labels_b.unsqueeze(1)
        #print(labels_a.shape)
        #labels_a = labels_a.argmax(-1)
        #labels_b = labels_b.argmax(-1)

        inputs = torch.cat([input_a,input_b],axis=0)
        labels = torch.cat([labels_a, labels_b])

        #labels  = labels.squeeze()
        #print(labels.shape)
        #labels = labels.argmax(-1)

        # Reset gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        # Compute output
        features_a = nets[0](input_a)
        features_b = nets[1](input_b)
        features_c = nets[2](inputs)

        pred_a = torch.squeeze(nets[3](features_a))
        pred_b = torch.squeeze(nets[3](features_b))
        pred_c = torch.squeeze(nets[3](features_c))

        loss = criterion(pred_a, labels_a) + criterion(pred_b, labels_b) + criterion(pred_c, labels)

        for n in model_a:
          layer_a = model_a[n]
          layer_b = model_b[n]
          layer_c = model_c[n]
          if (isinstance(layer_a,nn.Conv2d)):
            loss += lambda_reg * reg_loss(combo_fn(layer_a.weight,layer_b.weight),layer_c.weight)
            if (layer_a.bias is not None):
              loss += lambda_reg * reg_loss(combo_fn(layer_a.bias, layer_b.bias), layer_c.bias)

        # Update loss
        sum_loss[split] += loss.item()
        # Check parameter update
        if split == "train":
          # Compute gradients
          loss.backward()
          # Optimize
          optimizer.step()

        # Compute accuracy

        #https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/bcewithlogitsloss-and-model-accuracy-calculation/59293/ 2
        #pred_labels_a = (pred_a >= 0.0).long()  # Binarize predictions to 0 and 1
        #pred_labels_b = (pred_b >= 0.0).long()  # Binarize predictions to 0 and 1
        #pred_labels_c = (pred_c >= 0.0).long()  # Binarize predictions to 0 and 1

        #print(pred_a.shape)

        _,pred_label_a = torch.max(pred_a, dim = 1)
        pred_labels_a = (pred_label_a == labels_a).float()

        _,pred_label_b = torch.max(pred_b, dim = 1)
        pred_labels_b = (pred_label_b == labels_b).float()

        _,pred_label_c = torch.max(pred_c, dim = 1)
        pred_labels_c = (pred_label_c == labels).float()

        batch_accuracy_a = pred_labels_a.sum().item() / len(labels_a)
        batch_accuracy_b = pred_labels_b.sum().item() / len(labels_b)
        batch_accuracy_c = pred_labels_c.sum().item() / len(labels)

        # Update accuracy
        sum_accuracy[split][0] += batch_accuracy_a
        sum_accuracy[split][1] += batch_accuracy_b
        sum_accuracy[split][2] += batch_accuracy_c


        if (split=='train'):
          progbar.update(j, ta=batch_accuracy_c)

    if (progbar is not None):
      progbar.finish()
    # Compute epoch loss/accuracy
    epoch_loss = {split: sum_loss[split] / len(loaders[split][0]) for split in ["train", "val", "test"]}
    epoch_accuracy = {split: [sum_accuracy[split][i] / len(loaders[split][0]) for i in range(len(sum_accuracy[split])) ] for split in ["train", "val", "test"]}

    # # Store params at the best validation accuracy
    # if save_param and epoch_accuracy["val"] > best_val_accuracy:
    #   # torch.save(net.state_dict(), f"{net.__class__.__name__}_best_val.pth")
    #   torch.save(net.state_dict(), f"{model_name}_best_val.pth")
    #   best_val_accuracy = epoch_accuracy["val"]

    print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}:")
    # Update history
    for split in ["train", "val", "test"]:
      history_loss[split].append(epoch_loss[split])
      history_accuracy[split].append(epoch_accuracy[split])
      # Print info
      print(f"\t{split}\tLoss: {epoch_loss[split]:0.5}\tVGG 1:{epoch_accuracy[split][0]:0.5}"
            f"\tVGG 2:{epoch_accuracy[split][1]:0.5}\tVGG *:{epoch_accuracy[split][2]:0.5}")

    if save_param:
      torch.save({'vgg_a':nets[0].state_dict(),'vgg_b':nets[1].state_dict(),'vgg_star':nets[2].state_dict(),'classifier':nets[3].state_dict()},f'{model_name}.pth')


    test(nets[0], nets[3], test_loader_all)
    test(nets[1], nets[3], test_loader_all)
    test(nets[2], nets[3], test_loader_all)

    summed_state_dict = OrderedDict()

    for key in nets[2].state_dict():
      if key.find('conv') >=0:
        #print(key)
        summed_state_dict[key] = combo_fn(nets[0].state_dict()[key],nets[1].state_dict()[key])
      else:
        summed_state_dict[key] = nets[2].state_dict()[key]

    nets[2].load_state_dict(summed_state_dict)
    test(nets[2], nets[3], test_loader_all)
```

The edited parts are the last rows.